# Lower control arm mounting bolt replacement size. 2004 Mazda B3000

Tags: mazda, suspension

Need to know what size bolt for Mazda B3000 lower control arm mount

Comment: Can you show us exactly which bolt you are talking about so we can get you the right information? A picture could literally be worth a thousand words here.

Comment: How do I add a picture?

Comment: Click the "edit" just below the tags. Inside the edit box, there will be a small picture box with what looks to be a twin peaked mountain (or something). Click on that and a dialog box comes up. Drag and drop your image directly into the box from an Explorer window. Easy-peasy.